# Connect Google VPC to database hosted on Scaleway using Scaleway RPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nat, openvpn, vpc, google-cloud-vpn

I have on my hand :

- an Airflow instance created using Google Composer in a VPC
- a postgres database on Scaleway protected by Nebula Mesh with a configurated [RPN](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/dedibox-network/rpn/)

My goal is to connect Airflow with the postgres Database.

My first thought was to create a NAT Gateway with Nebula mesh running on the router with associated certificates to use the ssl connection. But if I understand everything right, I can't install Nebula on the Google's CloudNAT/CloudRouter. I would need to create a NAT Proxy VM myself, which I guess isn't the simpliest idea.

Another idea was to "connect the VPC" to the Scaleway RPN using [RPN VP](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/dedibox-network/rpn/how-to/use-rpn-vpn/) allowing me to bypass Nebula. But I'm not sure how to do so, I tried creating a CloudVPN but something went wrong in the process and I didn't catch any pong.

Can anyone hint me on the right process to solve my problem ? What would be the easiest way to do it ? I'm not fluent yet with cloud platform and networking, so I'm kinda lost in the heavy documentation !

Thank's in advance

Comment: Hi, 
In this article, you can find information related to Patterns for connecting other cloud service providers with Google Cloud [1]. It might be convenient for you to explore this article before trying to find the solution. Also, when you mentioned that you tried to create a cloud VPN and something went wrong, can you please provide more details about it?
[1] https://cloud.google.com/architecture/patterns-for-connecting-other-csps-with-gcp

Comment: @IsmaelClementeAguirre Hi, thanks for you awnser. Yes this is what I tried, the error I get is : establishing IKE_SA failed, peer not responding.

Comment: Issue “establishing IKE_SA failed” could be related to firewall configuration. Did you follow this guide for the cloud VPN connection creation in your project? If not, please check the “Completing the configuration” part[1]. Did you create a firewall rule to allow the connection?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-static-vpns#completing_the_configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [cloud-vpn only supports IPsec](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#specifications) and is not compatible with the OpenVPN protocol used by Scaleway's RPN-VPN.

To do a site-to-site vpn connection you'll need one of those:

- cloud-vpn compatible ipsec gateway on a Scaleway server **connected to RPN v1**
- a custom gateway connected on gcp with an openvpn client to [RPN-VPN](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/dedibox-network/rpn/how-to/use-rpn-vpn/)